# Google Sheets formula to get text between colons

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a formula which can get the text and numbers in between colons from within a cell. I've tried regexreplace punctuation however I need the periods between version numbers, also tried some regex and find formulas however can't figure it out sadly, would much appreciate some help.

| Input | Expected output |
| --- | --- |
| cpe:2.3:a:caldera:openlinux_server:3.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:* | cpe 2.3 a caldera openlinux server 3.1 |
| cpe:2.3:a:immunix:immunix:6.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:* | cpe 2 3 a immunix immunix 6.2 |
| cpe:2.3:o:mandrakesoft:mandrake_linux:7.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:* | cpe 2.3 o mandrakesoft mandrake linux 7.1 |

Ideally this will remove any asterisks (*) and underscores (_), and remove "cpe 2 3 a" however this isn't entirely necessary.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, "_|:|\*", " ")))
```

[image]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A, 
 "_|:|\*", " ")), ".+\d+.\d+ . (.+)")))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that's exactly what I wanted. As a follow-up is it possible to parse from the fourth colon onwards? so in the first example I would want the output after caldera.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I did score it as helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I want to propose a simpler alternative where you can understand everything that is going on.

### Solution:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A3, "_|:|\*", " ")," ","@",4),LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A1: A3, "_|:|\*", " ")," ","@",4))- FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A3, "_|:|\*", "_|:|\*", " " ")," ","@",4)))))`

### Step by step.

You can try saving the results of each step in cells in column B to see how the solution is constructed.

1. Replace all unwanted characters with blanks with [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en):
   `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"_|:|\*", " ")`
2. Replace the fourth blank space with a special character (in this case @) with [SUBSITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en):
   `=SUBSTITUTE(B1," ","@",4)`
3. Obtain the desired substring by taking all the characters after the special character. Combine [RIGHT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087?hl=en) and [FIND](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126?hl=en) to achieve this:
   `=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)- FIND("@",B2))`
4. Remove trailing whitespace with [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en):
   `=TRIM(B3)`
5. Apply [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) to modify a range in the first step instead of a specific cell.
6. Put all steps together in one function